# Jquery Find the length of paragraph tag

Tags: jquery

I have a paragraph tag like this `<p id="data">I am testing</p>`.
How do I find the length of this text inside paragraph tag ?

```
$("#data").length;
```

It output 1, if I do not have any text too. Even for this 'I am testing' it outputs as 1.

Comment: `$.trim( $('#data').text() ).length;`

Comment: Try this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120736/count-characters-in-paragraph-using-jquery-not-for-input-textarea

Comment: @adeneo:I tried yours before posting here,it did not give me expected result.

Comment: Works for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zv88k/) ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using jQuery.
Try this

```
$("#data").text().length
```

You have to pass the elements contents to the length function.
Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/69JL9/

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the length of the content, something like this:

```
$("#data").text().length;
```

*With your example `$("#data").length;` you will get the number of elements that match your selector, therefor your output is `1`, no matter if the element has any content or not.*